# what type of user defined UDFs are mostly written in Apache Hive and Apache PIG in Hadoop?

Tags: hive, apache-pig

What kind of user defined UDFs are usually customized or written in PIG and HIVE in Bigdata and Hadoop projects OR what type of user defined UDFs are mostly written in Apache Hive and Apache PIG in Hadoop?

Comment: you can write UDF for the functionality that you can't achieve with existing UDFs and if the functionality will be used for more than one place

Comment: That is correct, if we already have some UDF available we won't write it again, i was asking about some example? what are the scenarios we may need to customize some of them?